# Establish a connection through socks with socket library

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, socks

I have this script that simply uses a list of socks and tries to connect to a host. But it always shows this error:

```
  File "*.py", line 38, in requestsocks
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "/home/*/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/socks.py", line 729, in connect
    _BaseSocket.connect(self, proxy_addr)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Here is the code:

```
import socket,socks,random

def checkurl():
    global url
    global url2
    global urlport
    url = input("Insert URL: ")
    if url[0]+url[1]+url[2]+url[3] == "www.":
        url = "http://" + url
    elif url[0]+url[1]+url[2]+url[3] == "http":
        pass
    else:
        url = "http://" + url

    try:
        url2 = url.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").split('/')[0].split(":")[0]
    except:
        url2 = url.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").split('/')[0]

    try:
        urlport = url.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").split('/')[0].split(':')[1]
    except:
        urlport = "80"

def proxylist():
    global entries
    out_file = str(input("Enter the proxy list: "))
    entries = open(out_file).readlines()
    requestsocks()

def requestsocks(): 
    while True:
        proxy = random.choice(entries).strip().split(':')
        host = str(url2)
        port = int(urlport)
        socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, proxy[0], proxy[1], True)
        s = socks.socksocket()
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.sendall('Hello world')

checkurl()
proxylist()
```

I don't know how can I solve this. Ideas?
P.S. I've taken the socks list from here: https://www.socks-proxy.net/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done much with the sockets library, but it's asking for an integer for both host and port. Try getting the IP like this.

Add this ------> host = socket.gethostbyname(host)

```
def requestsocks(): 
    while True:
        proxy = random.choice(entries).strip().split(':')
        host = str(url2)
        # convert url to IP address
        host = socket.gethostbyname(host)
        port = int(urlport)
        socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, proxy[0], proxy[1], True)
        s = socks.socksocket()
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.sendall('Hello world')
```